# Iframe sandbox security

Tags: html, django, iframe, django-templates

I was planning to create an app where the users can create their own blog page and others can link it in my web, like facebook. And then, I thought about using `iframe` with the `sandbox` attribute to view the page with the `safe` filter in the template. So, is it safe to implement it in this way??? Or is there any other way around? Please, any help will be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `safe` filter in the template is your way of telling django that you can vouch for any content appearing there and that it isn't malicious. I'd therefore say it's not secure to use for user-generated content. An iframe is also unnecessary here. You might want to look at something like [bleach](https://django-bleach.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for user-generated html content.